# How do I access the photos on my SD card on elementary OS?

Tags: files, disk-management, mount

I am new to Linux and StackExchange, and I'm having trouble finding my SD card so I can import my photos into GIMP for editing.

I have tried various commands using the terminal and I've looked in the Files application, but I can't find my SD card. The SD card is a SanDisk 128gb SD card.

My computer is an HP Envy x360 Convertible Laptop 15m-dr0xx and my SD card is plugged into the reader on its side.

Comment: What is the file system on your SD card?

Comment: Have you tried the not-Windows-specific steps of this Troubleshooting? https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-Notebooks/SD-card-reader-not-working/td-p/6188613

Answer (score 2):

All connected media (CD, flash disk, SD) should automatically appear in this section in Files:

[image: Files → Left panel → Devices]

Try to be patient, it can theoretically take somewhere around a minute if your computer has a bad day

If it doesn't appear, chances are you're missing a driver for the SD reader. Try running `lspci` and look for the model of your reader. It's probably `Realtech RTS####` (where `#` are some digits). Then search for a corresponding driver on the [Realtech website](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/card-reader-solutions-card-reader-controllers-software).

If the correct driver isn't there, you're in a bad luck. Now you're allowed to swear and be disrespectful of those Windows-centric manufacturers that can't even provide proper drivers for their hardware.

If you're feeling adventurous, there is [an issue on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/492515/134205) which solved the same problem for a different model of HP Envy. You can follow the instructions there and compile the driver yourself. Which isn't exactly easy for a newcoming user, luckily there's [a sort of tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/q/177329/134205) available.

Comment: As you say: "be patient" it should be noted that most SD cards are notoriously slow to mount compared to other media, and it might take a bit for something of 128 Gb